# Using oracle hints

Tags: oracle, hints

I am trying the following query to list the first 10 rows from fisgen table:

```
SELECT /*+FIRST_ROWS(10)*/ salute, gender, fid
FROM fisgen;
```

The hint is not executed. All the rows from the table are returned.
What should I do so that the hint is executed?

Comment: The hint will ***not*** limit the number of rows returned. It is merely a "suggestion" to the optimizer to adapt the execution plan to the fact that you are only interested in the first 10 rows. But it will **not** change the _result_ of the query

Comment: While this statement is true in this case, Oracle does have at least one hint which *does* change the result of a query. It's very nasty and yet another reason why I don't use Oracle anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Your query doesn't ask for the first ten rows. For that you need to write something like:

```
SELECT salute, gender, fid
FROM fisgen
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
```

The hint `first_rows(10)` is only needed to instruct the optimizer that it should optimize for retrieving the first 10 rows as fast as possible rather than optimizing for whatever percentage of the table the optimizer thinks it will get.

Don't include the hint unless the optimizer gets it wrong.

Comment: But Iam not able to achieve whatever I give inside the hint.Eg :SELECT /*+ NO_USE_HASH(j f)*/
* from journal j,fisgen fg
WHERE j.fid=fg.fid;  The explain plan still returns hash as the join technique.

Comment: Why do you want to use the hint? Don't use a hint if you don't need it.

Comment: Iam trying to display the query execution plans for various join techniques as part of my project..So Iam using hints to display join techniques

Comment: I suggest you go to Jonathan Lewis' site. He covers many of the hints and join techniques.

Comment: Get a copy of Cost Based Oracle Fundamentals. It rocks